# Using AngularJS $routeparams with Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, routes, laravel-5

In using AngularJS on top of Laravel, assuming I have this route in Laravel:

```
Route::get('/admin/', function() { return View::make('pages.writer'); });
```

which makes a view that loads AngularJS components, including `$routeProvider`, and that the configuration is like so:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/writer/:publicationName?', {
   templateUrl: '/templates/writer.html',
   controller: 'WriterCtrl',
   caseInsensitiveMatch: true
 }).otherwise({
   templateUrl: '/templates/library.html',
   controller: 'LibraryCtrl'
 });
```

If I call the URL: `/admin/writer/My-Favorite-Publication`, I get a Laravel error because the route doesn't exist. Is there a way to tell Laravel when Angular routing takes over for a particular URL (i.e. anything after `/admin/`), so that I can use `$routeParams`.

Comment: have you enabled `html5mode`?

Comment: @PankajParkar yes I have

Comment: I think by putting `<base href="/admin">` on your html `head` tag will fix the issue

Comment: @PankajParkar I did that too! I should perhaps clarify that the URL is called directly, not via `$location.path()`.

Comment: @PankajParkar none of those will work. Before anything is returned to the browser or angularjs app it first needs to pass through Laravel and the application breaks at this stage before Angular app is executed

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Oh that cool..I didn't know about this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a **catch-all** route that will return the base view that runs **AngularJS** app and let **AngularJS** handle the rest of the routing.

This will do the trick:

```
Route::get('/admin/{ignore?}', function() { 
  return View::make('pages.writer'); 
})->where('ignore', '.*');
```

This will make everything that starts with **/admin** match this **Laravel** route.